# Is it possible to select only keys (not whole tuple) from Tarantool DB?

Tags: tarantool

Is it possible to select only keys (not whole tuple) from Tarantool DB space?

Is there a function similar to something like this:
   `keys = box.space.tester:select_keys{55}`

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such thing in the protocol to get only part of the data. Also, there is no such thing in Lua API you are referring to.